# Call Controller function from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm working on some codes. Here's my code

**jQuery**

```
duration = 30;
var countdown = setInterval(timer,1000);
var url = window.location.origin + '/pro/index.php/Test';

function timer(){
  duration = duration - 1; 
  if(duration<=0){
    clearInterval(countdown);
    window.location(url+'/next');
  }
}
```

I want to redirect and run function in `Test/next`. In `next()` method, it will rule where the link should go. `url` helper also has been added automatically in `Loader`

**Controller**

```
public $num;
public $val;

public function index(){
  // get the value from GET method
  $this->num = $this->input->get('num');
  $this->val = $this->input->get('val');
}

public function next(){
  $x = $this->num;
  $x = $x + 1;
  if($x < 4){
    redirect(site_url('index.php/Test?x='.$x/.'&num='.$this->num));
  }
  else{
    // it will redirect to another page
    // redirect(site_url('index.php/Home'));
    echo 'x = '.$x.', num = '.$this->num;
  }
```

(The codes above have been simplified).

The method has been run, but the url was `localhost/pro/index.php/Test/next` and echo-ing :

> x = , num =

It seems like the global property doesn't work for the function called from JS/jQuery. Any explanation or solution for this?

Comment: can you add a construct function and do `$this->num = $this->input->get('num');` `$this->val = $this->input->get('val');` inside that function.

Comment: it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need ajax calling.
In your View file

```
<button class="call_ajax" name="submit">Call Ajax</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.call_ajax').click(function(){
        var value1 = 'some data';
        var value2 = 'some data'; 
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('your_controller/your_function'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                key1: value1,
                key2: value2
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(url) {
            window.location.href = url;
         }
        });
    });</script>
```

in your Controller

```
your_function(){
    $data1 = $this->input->post('key1');
    $data2 = $this->input->post('key2');
    // do Data Processing
    // For return some data ; 
    echo "https://some-webiste-url/";

    // FOR Array

    echo json_encode($any_data_array);

}
```

NOTE : controller Function called from ajax will not do redirection . If you want to direct to some other url , you have to do that in the Javascript Section Using